# Installing suds in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3, suds

I am having some difficulties with installing python's module "suds-0.4" in python 3.3. Whenever I try to install using the standard "setup.py install" type command I have used for other packages, it works correctly. However when I try on suds-0.4 and in python 3.3, I receive that "ImportError: no module named "client" with is obviously wrong since client is located inside of the directory. I am running this in command line inside the directory where setup.py is located.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As it currently stands, `suds` doesn't support python3, so for now your only options is to use an alternative version of suds.

If you [search on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=suds&submit=search), you'll find several forks that should work - I've successfully used `suds-jurko` before, but `suds-philipem` seems to be the most advanced version right now.

Comment: from the suds-philipem page on pypi: `**** THIS PACKAGE IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED ****
Jurko's doing a much better job at this than I ever did. Go use his fork instead.`